# 7-Zip command line add only specific file to archive?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

There's lots of questions asking how to add only files with a particular file extension to an archive, but to my great surprise it seems like no one wants to add a single file to an archive.

How do I add a single specific file to an archive with the 7-Zip command line?

Comment: You can expect within the command line structure that a wildcard can be replaced with a single filename, or as RaziAbbasi notes in his answer, a list of filenames.

Answer (score 10):

The approach would be the same, just the bit at the end would be a little different.

So for a particular file extension you would do this:

```
7z a -t7z archive.7z *.txt
```

You have just added all the .txt files.

But let's say you want to add a pdf and a doc to that, you would do this:

```
7z a -t7z archive.7z file.pdf file2.doc
```

Note: This won't create a new archive.7z, rather it will just add file.pdf and file2.doc to the archive.7z you created earlier.

Comment: When adding a file to an existing archive, you can omit the option -t7z